# Swift touchesBegan causes Xcode crash while still performing function in touchesEnded

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, touchesbegan

I am new to programming, so I'm sure its a simple fix. However, I have it so that when I touch a specific sprite node, it adds a ball and target. Once I release my finger it sends the ball to the target. However, if I try to send another ball before the first ball is finished, Xcode crashes.

Please Help!!

ERROR = reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:

Code:

```
//
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

            let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) == self.slingshot {

            addBall()
            addTarget()

            isFingerTouching = true

            }
    }




 override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Update to new touch location */

    if isFingerTouching {

        var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)


                var slingholderY = slingholder.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y)
                var slingholderX = slingholder.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)

        slingholderY = min(slingholderY, 155)
        slingholderY = max(slingholderY, 89)

        slingholderX = min(slingholderX, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 40)
        slingholderX = max(slingholderX, CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 40)

            slingholder.position = CGPointMake(slingholderX, slingholderY)

        leftsling.yScale = (155 / slingholder.position.y)*0.6
        leftsling.xScale = (slingholder.position.x / 383)*0.6

        rightsling.yScale = (155 / slingholder.position.y)*0.6
        rightsling.xScale = (383 / slingholder.position.x)*0.6

        slingholder.yScale = (89 / slingholder.position.y)
        slingholder.xScale = (89 / slingholder.position.y)

        ball.yScale = 2*(89 / slingholder.position.y)
        ball.xScale = 2*(89 / slingholder.position.y)
        ball.position = slingholder.position

        slingholder.zRotation = 0.3*((slingholder.position.x - 383)/40)

        target.position.x = 768 - (9.57 * (slingholder.position.x - 343))
        target.position.y = max(10, 300)
        target.position.y = (self.frame.size.height - self.scoreboard.size.height - 300) + (9.85 * (89 - slingholder.position.y) + 150)

            }
    }


    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

      sendBall()
      isFingerTouching = false

    }

    //Check if bird reaches right or left side
    func checkIfBirdReachesOtherSide () {
        for child in self.children {
            if(child.position.x > self.frame.width+20) {
                self.removeChildrenInArray([child])
            }
            if(child.position.x < -20) {
                self.removeChildrenInArray([child])
            }
        }

}

    func addBall () {

                ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 155)
                ball.xScale = 1.0
                ball.yScale = 1.0
                ball.zPosition = 4
                self.addChild(ball)

            }

    func addTarget ()  {


        target.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: slingholder.position.y + 200)
        target.zPosition = 4
        self.addChild(target)
    }

   func sendBall () {

        let moveToTarget = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(target.position.x, target.position.y), duration: 0.5)
        let scaleBallUp = SKAction.scaleBy(1.0, duration: 0.2)
        let scaleBallDown = SKAction.scaleBy(0.3, duration: 0.3)

        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)

        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleBallUp, scaleBallDown, remove])

        let ballGroupAction = SKAction.group([moveToTarget, sequence])
        ball.runAction(ballGroupAction)

        target.runAction(remove)

        let moveSlingholder = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 155), duration:1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0)

        let scaleSling = SKAction.scaleXTo(0.6, y: 0.6, duration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0)

        let scaleSlingHolder = SKAction.scaleXTo(0.6, y: 0.6, duration: 1, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0)

        let rotateSlingholder = SKAction.rotateToAngle(0, duration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0)

        let slingHolderBundledMovement = SKAction.group([moveSlingholder, rotateSlingholder, scaleSlingHolder])


        slingholder.runAction(slingHolderBundledMovement)
        leftsling.runAction(scaleSling)
        rightsling.runAction(scaleSling)

    }

}
//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `addTarget` and `addBall` method.

You can add an SKNode only to one parent. And there you add the same target and same ball everytime you touch the screen. So you should add the ball and the target only once and update the position everytime.

So you could in your `didMoveToView` method add the two nodes:

```
addChild(ball)
addChild(target)
```

and only update the position etc. in your methods without adding it again each time the method is called.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer so that other people can find it easier?